# c# CefSharp Flash Problems

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm running a game on chromium in c# and this game is flash supported.

So when it first opens it tells me: "Right-click to run Adobe Flash Player" https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsgzN.png

My question this:
How can it run automatically without right clicking and selecting "Run"?

**What I've Tried:**

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-npapi", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer32_32_0_0_363.dll");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", "32.0.0.363");
```

**And**

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-system-flash", "1");
```

But not working. Thank you for your help already.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3012#issuecomment-573542466

Comment: My Cef version: 79.1.360. and "CefCommandLineArgs" method not available. [link](https://hizliresim.com/2KNUDg)

Comment: Your question says auto play.

Comment: Yea but didn't work?

Comment: The upstream issue is https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2768/allow-flash-to-play-without-user just saying it didn't work is meaningless as you've not shown what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

I am using CefSharp v 75.1.143
and the solution lies in the following settings

```
if (settings.CefCommandLineArgs.ContainsKey("enable-system-flash"))
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("enable-system-flash");

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-system-flash", "1");

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "pepflashplayer32_32_0_0_344.dll"));
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", "32.0.0.344");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["plugin-policy"] = "allow";
```

especially the last one!

Comment: You remove enable-system-flash only to re-add it, completely unnessicary.

Comment: I can swear that from version 65 onwards it is necessary to do this, because it is already present by default to false

Comment: Starting with version 81 flash is disabled by default and can only be enabled for a limited time as support is being removed from chromium see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3048 in version 79 and below system wide flash is enabled by default https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.Core/AbstractCefSettings.h#L53

Comment: The value of 1 passed to enable-system-flash is always ignored by Chromium. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2858

Comment: I had used the same version of code without this check with multiple versions of Cefsharp  53, 57, 63 and 65. Until with version 75 I had to use this trick and update the plugin version that was out of date. In debug from that if it passes us with value 0, so I implemented this solution and it works.

Comment: My comments are only for the enable-system-flash command line argument. For anyone else make sure you are aware flash support is being removed from chromium shortly.  Microsoft are actively uninstalling flash from systems https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15959&p=47204#p47204

Comment: I know the problem, in fact I am currently busy recompiling the CEF  with support for .mp4 files, as you suggested in another post. But I am having a lot of problems in the w10 environment that I can list. See my post on https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16568&p=47561#p47561